# How to not include field in object if value is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
const exampleFunction = (var1, var2, var3) => {
    return const targetObject = {
        var1,
        var2,
        var3,
    },
};
```

var2 and var3 are optional variables.

If all 3 variables were send to this function, then I need to return object with 3 fields.

If var2 is undefined, I need to return object with 2 fields only.
If var3 is undefined, I need to return object with 2 fields only.

If var2 and var3 are undefined, I need to return object with 1 field only.

Comment: Create the object. Add properties if-they-are-defined. In this case (if var2 is always defined 'before' var3, eg, it would be simpler) one could also create a few different 'defined' permutations. Also, maybe just an array..?

Comment: With your `If var2 is undefined, I need to return object with 2 fields only` it sounds as if `undefined` is *specifically* being passed as an argument? Eg `exampleFunction('foo', undefined, 'bar')`? Seems odd

Comment: @CertainPerformance When the value comes from another variable, it's not odd. Say for example, var1,2,3 comes from form elements, or from an API call in NodeJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
const exampleFunction = (var1, var2, var3) => {
    const targetObject = {};
    if (var1) targetObject.var1 = var1;
    if (var2) targetObject.var2 = var2;
    if (var3) targetObject.var3 = var3;

    return targetObject;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse` together with `JSON.stringify` since `JSON.stringify` will skip `undefined`, `Function`, and `Symbol` during the conversion. If those types are in an array, they will be automatically censored to `null` in that array by `JSON.stringify`.

```js
const exampleFunction = (var1, var2, var3) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
  var1,
  var2,
  var3
}))

const outputs = exampleFunction(undefined, 2, undefined)
console.log(outputs)
```

Outputs: `{ var2: 2 }`

Comment: This is a nice answer. But will be erroneous with Date objects afaik

Comment: just try `new Date` instead of `2` and check the type. type changes from object to string

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to build the object and then get rid of the undefined values

```
const targetObj = {var1, var2, var3}
Object.keys(targetObj).forEach((key) => (targetObj[key] == null) && delete targetObj[key]);
```

Using JSON stringify and parse looks good if you are guaranteed that var1,2,3 are primitive variables. Otherwise they will be converted to strings(For instance Date Objects).

Answer (score 0):

If it is not an inconvenience to use the traditional function statement you could try

```
function anotherExampleFunction(var1, var2, var3) {
    return Object.assign({}, Array.from(arguments).filter(argument => argument !== undefined));
}

const result1 = anotherExampleFunction(1, 2, 3);
const result2 = anotherExampleFunction(1, 2, undefined);
const result3 = anotherExampleFunction(1, undefined, 3);
const result4 = anotherExampleFunction(1, undefined, undefined);

console.log(result1, result2, result3, result4)
```

output

```
{ '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3 } { '0': 1, '1': 2 } { '0': 1, '1': 3 } { '0': 1 }
```